# Salesforce MFA effects on API integrations

Tags: api, mulesoft, mfa

We are having integration with the Salesforce from the Mulesoft. Now, as Salesforce is planning to roll-out MFA for all apps. Will it affect our API integration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, multi-factor authentication (MFA) only affects authentication for users who log in to Salesforce via their browser or the Marketing Cloud mobile app.

MFA does not affect REST or SOAP API requests.

[image]

[Reference 1](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000352937&type=1&mode=1),
[Reference 2](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_overview_mfa_faq_api.htm&type=5)

Also, read out this [guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/security_require_2fa_api.htm) to understand, how it works

Comment: There is also MFA for APIs([ref](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.security_require_2fa_api.htm&type=5)). I tried enabling this type of MFA & with this our integrations can no longer use APIs. Any workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It's not clear from almost all of the documentation I've seen on this, and is buried in one of the helpful references from StackExchange member Shivankur Naikwade, but applications using API-only access will fail if the relevant API user's access token was generated using password login. To prevent this outcome, API users must login using MFA before MFA is enforced.

> Users with these permissions must complete multi-factor authentication
> when they log in to Salesforce through the UI. Users with mobile
> devices can use the Salesforce Authenticator mobile app or a
> third-party authenticator app as a verification method for MFA. Then
> they can use verification codes (time-based one-time passwords, or
> TOTP) from the app for multi-factor authentication. (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.230.0.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/security_require_2fa_api.htm)

Given the date I am writing this issue and the paucity of warnings about it, I worry that many administrators will experience what StackExchange member Akshay commented about here on June 18, 2021, without sufficient time for remediation.