# API login after MFA enforcement

Tags: oauth2, apexrest, restresource, accesstoken, mfa

With the enforcement of MFA coming next year, I've started to test an API I wrote for a client that allows their website to talk to Salesforce. It's working fine right now, but if I enable High Assurance on the profile, I can no longer use the API.

The website first retrieves an access token and then uses that in the header for all subsequent calls.

With High Assurance selected on the profile, I am able to authenticate and get an access token back, but when I use that access token in the next call to retrieve some data (using a custom RestResource class), I get the following response:

```
[
    {
        "message": "This session is not valid for use with the REST API",
        "errorCode": "INVALID_SESSION_ID"
    }
]
```

This is the connected app settings:
[image]

Before testing today, the OAuth scope was set to web (and working fine). It was set to api for testing when the screenshot was taken but has since been put back to web.

Any help or advice on this would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Andy

Comment: While this doesn't answer your question, [MFA is not required for API-only clients](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/347158/salesforce-mfa-effects-on-api-integrations).

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour might happen due to scope being used in your connected app settings.

If we try to test using just API scope, it would expect for REST API or BULK API call to access or manage data in Salesforce.

[image]

However, as you mentioned you have implementation for client that allows their website to talk to Salesforce.So, the web scope comes in picture for this purpose and should work fine when set to web scope.

[image]

For connected apps, only the OAuth 2.0 refresh token flow, web server flow, and user-agent flows support using API logins with the high assurance MFA session security level. All other OAuth flows, such as the JSON Web Token (JWT) bearer token flow, block API logins with the high assurance MFA session security level. It’s possible that users are prompted to verify their identity twice with high assurance MFA during an OAuth approval flow. The first challenge occurs in the UI session. The second challenge happens when the access token is bridged into the UI. This second challenge is triggered because the high assurance MFA session security level isn’t transferred to the access token.

If you still find any discrepancies in the behaviour in your particular use case, then consider [raising a case with Salesforce support](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.workcom_contact_support.htm&type=5) to get clearer insight for your query.

Additional reference [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_tokens_scopes.htm&type=5)